# ping: unknown host google.com and host unreachableping 8.8.8.8

Tags: networking, server, dns, dhcp, raspberrypi

I don't know why but when i try to ping any site or ip address there the pc display those errors.
i create an access point on my raspberry with ubuntu mate 16.04
and i create a connection between my laptop and raspberry to access to the internet.

I've also used a static ip.
The file `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
#interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback


#The ethernet network interface
#iface eth0 inet dhcp
auto eth0
#allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 192.168.137.150
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.137.1
        dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4


#The wireless network interface
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
        address 192.168.42.1
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.137.1
        pre-up iptables-restore
```

The file `/etc/resolv`:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

The command `ifconfig`:

```
pi@pi-desktop:~$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:6b:8f:c8
          inet addr:192.168.137.150  Bcast:192.168.137.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::ba27:ebff:fe6b:8fc8/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2239 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2017 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:148422 (148.4 KB)  TX bytes:253060 (253.0 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:190 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:190 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
          RX bytes:14290 (14.2 KB)  TX bytes:14290 (14.2 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:3e:da:9d
          inet addr:192.168.42.1  Bcast:192.168.42.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::ba27:ebff:fe3e:da9d/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2196 errors:0 dropped:2196 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:47 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:365979 (365.9 KB)  TX bytes:6924 (6.9 KB)
```

The file `/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf`:

```
#
# Sample configuration file for ISC dhcpd for Debian
#
# Attention: If /etc/ltsp/dhcpd.conf exists, that will be used as
# configuration file instead of this file.
#
#

# The ddns-updates-style parameter controls whether or not the server will
# attempt to do a DNS update when a lease is confirmed. We default to the
# behavior of the version 2 packages ('none', since DHCP v2 didn't
# have support for DDNS.)
ddns-update-style none;

# option definitions common to all supported networks...
#option domain-name "example.org";
#option domain-name-servers ns1.example.org, ns2.example.org;

default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;

# If this DHCP server is the official DHCP server for the local
# network, the authoritative directive should be uncommented.
authoritative;

# Use this to send dhcp log messages to a different log file (you also
# have to hack syslog.conf to complete the redirection).
log-facility local7;

# No service will be given on this subnet, but declaring it helps the
# DHCP server to understand the network topology.

#subnet 10.152.187.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
#}

# This is a very basic subnet declaration.

#subnet 10.254.239.0 netmask 255.255.255.224 {
#  range 10.254.239.10 10.254.239.20;
#  option routers rtr-239-0-1.example.org, rtr-239-0-2.example.org;
#}

# This declaration allows BOOTP clients to get dynamic addresses,
# which we don't really recommend.

#subnet 10.254.239.32 netmask 255.255.255.224 {
#  range dynamic-bootp 10.254.239.40 10.254.239.60;
#  option broadcast-address 10.254.239.31;
#  option routers rtr-239-32-1.example.org;
#}

# A slightly different configuration for an internal subnet.
#subnet 10.5.5.0 netmask 255.255.255.224 {
#  range 10.5.5.26 10.5.5.30;
#  option domain-name-servers ns1.internal.example.org;
#  option domain-name "internal.example.org";
#  option subnet-mask 255.255.255.224;
#  option routers 10.5.5.1;
#  option broadcast-address 10.5.5.31;
#  default-lease-time 600;
#  max-lease-time 7200;
#}

# Hosts which require special configuration options can be listed in
# host statements.   If no address is specified, the address will be
# allocated dynamically (if possible), but the host-specific information
# will still come from the host declaration.
#host passacaglia {
#  hardware ethernet 0:0:c0:5d:bd:95;
#  filename "vmunix.passacaglia";
#  server-name "toccata.fugue.com";
#}

# Fixed IP addresses can also be specified for hosts.   These addresses
# should not also be listed as being available for dynamic assignment.
# Hosts for which fixed IP addresses have been specified can boot using
# BOOTP or DHCP.   Hosts for which no fixed address is specified can only
# be booted with DHCP, unless there is an address range on the subnet
# to which a BOOTP client is connected which has the dynamic-bootp flag
# set.
#host fantasia {
#  hardware ethernet 08:00:07:26:c0:a5;
#  fixed-address fantasia.fugue.com;
#}

# Fixed IP addresses can also be specified for hosts.   These addresses
# should not also be listed as being available for dynamic assignment.
# Hosts for which fixed IP addresses have been specified can boot using
# BOOTP or DHCP.   Hosts for which no fixed address is specified can only
# be booted with DHCP, unless there is an address range on the subnet
# to which a BOOTP client is connected which has the dynamic-bootp flag
# set.
#host fantasia {
#  hardware ethernet 08:00:07:26:c0:a5;
#  fixed-address fantasia.fugue.com;
#}

# You can declare a class of clients and then do address allocation
# based on that.   The example below shows a case where all clients
# in a certain class get addresses on the 10.17.224/24 subnet, and all
# other clients get addresses on the 10.0.29/24 subnet.

#class "foo" {
#  match if substring (option vendor-class-identifier, 0, 4) = "SUNW";
#}

#shared-network 224-29 {
#  subnet 10.17.224.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
#    option routers rtr-224.example.org;
#  }
#  subnet 10.0.29.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
#    option routers rtr-29.example.org;
#  }
#  pool {
#    allow members of "foo";
#    range 10.17.224.10 10.17.224.250;
#  }
#  pool {
#    deny members of "foo";
#    range 10.0.29.10 10.0.29.230;
#  }
#}

domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4

#subnet 192.168.42.0 netmask 255.255.255.0
#{
#       range 192.168.42.10 192.168.42.50;
#       option broadcast-address 192.168.42.255;
#       option routers 192.168.42.1;
#       default-lease-time 600;
#       max-lease-time 7200;
#       option domain-name "local";
#       option domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4;
#}
```

isc-dhcp-server status:

```
pi@pi-desktop:~$ service isc-dhcp-server status
● isc-dhcp-server.service - ISC DHCP IPv4 server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/isc-dhcp-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since mar 2018-03-20 18:15:55 CET; 54min ago
     Docs: man:dhcpd(8)
  Process: 1116 ExecStart=/bin/sh -ec      CONFIG_FILE=/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf;      if [ -f /etc/ltsp/dhcpd.conf ]; then CONFIG_FILE=/etc/ltsp/dhcpd.conf; fi;      [ -e /var/lib/dhcp/dhcpd.le
 Main PID: 1116 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

mar 20 18:15:55 pi-desktop sh[1116]: Configuration file errors encountered -- exiting
mar 20 18:15:55 pi-desktop sh[1116]: If you think you have received this message due to a bug rather
mar 20 18:15:55 pi-desktop sh[1116]: than a configuration issue please read the section on submitting
mar 20 18:15:55 pi-desktop sh[1116]: bugs on either our web page at www.isc.org or in the README file
mar 20 18:15:55 pi-desktop sh[1116]: before submitting a bug.  These pages explain the proper
mar 20 18:15:55 pi-desktop sh[1116]: process and the information we find helpful for debugging..
mar 20 18:15:55 pi-desktop sh[1116]: exiting.
mar 20 18:15:55 pi-desktop systemd[1]: isc-dhcp-server.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
mar 20 18:15:55 pi-desktop systemd[1]: isc-dhcp-server.service: Unit entered failed state.
mar 20 18:15:55 pi-desktop systemd[1]: isc-dhcp-server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

someone can help me?

Comment: Can the raspberry pi ping 8.8.8.8?

Answer (score 0):

Can you specify the devices on which you configure your interface (rasperry or laptop) ?

First, ensure that your Raspberry can reach internet (ping 8.8.8.8).

**Don't forget to enable forwarding in your Raspberry :**

Put `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` in `/etc/sysctl.conf` then reboot or simply `echo 1> /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`.

**Check firewall (iptables) :**

Exec `iptables -L` as root anc check if rules block your traffic (the DNS port for example) in both of your devices (latptop and rasp).

**Configure ISCP DHCP SERVER**

It's look like you have an error in your `isc-dhcp-server` configuration.
Before try to configure any domain name server, properly connect your devices.

```
subnet 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
  range 192.168.1.10 192.168.1.100;
}
```

**Debug commands**

- Check your ip configuration with the command `ip address`
- Try `sudo dhclient -v [interface]` on your laptor (replace interface with your interface name) and see what happend (if you correctly get an IP adress from your DHCP server or not).
- Verify if your laptop can communicate with your raspberry with the command `ping [rasp ip]`

  - If this fail, check the route of your laptop with the command `ip route` and ensure that the route to the rasp is correctly defined